# How to use modifiers from primevue dynamically

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, storybook, primevue

I am using Tooltip from Primevue (https://primevue.org/tooltip/) and using it in a storybook file. (https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/get-started/introduction).

I want to use 'v-tooltip' attribute or modifier like this with directions '.left', which is working fine statically.

```
template: <Button type='button'  v-bind='args'  v-tooltip.left='args.tooltipMsg'  />
```

but i want to pass the direction dynamically such as 'v-tooltip.right', 'v-tooltip.bottom' etc.

Here is my complete code:

```
import Button from "primevue/button"
import Tooltip from "primevue/tooltip"


export default {
  title: "Components/Tooltip",
  component: { Button },
  argTypes: {
    label: {
      control: "text",
    },
    
    tooltipMsg: {
      control: "text",
    },
    tooltipDirection: {
      options: ["top", "bottom", "right", "left"],
      control: { type: "select" },
    },
  },
}

const Template = (args) => ({
  components: { Button },
  setup() {
    
    return { args }
  },
  directives: {
    tooltip: Tooltip,
  },

  template:
    "<Button type='button' v-bind='args' v-tooltip='args.tooltipMsg'  />",
})
export const Primary = Template.bind({})
Primary.args = {
  label: "Primary",
  tooltipMsg: "Enter ur name",
}
```

Comment: Can't you do:

`\`<Button type="button" v-bind="args" v-tooltip.${args.tooltipDirection}='args.tooltipMsg'>\``

Comment: No, that's not possible either, i've testet that as well but no success.

Comment: Another question one month later: isn't it missing some styling? I had a case where the tooltip was displaying but missing some styles from PrimeVue because we were not loading all of them in Storybook and the tooltip was nowhere to be seen, but the source code.